# QGIS Georeferencer - Image file imports too small

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I am trying to georeference a largish aerial image (50MB) to some GIS data I have and import it as a background.  However the image imports extremely small - so small I can't see it!

I am using QGIS and the Georeferencer plugin.  I select about 7 control points randomly across the image and I am using the thin plate spline with nearest neighbour resampling.  The error is `0.00768`.  I have tried several transformation settings and set the target CRS to the project CRS, but get similar results. The control points appear in QGIS in the right positions.

This is a screenshot of the settings used.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you, tou want to use an aerial photograph to digitize something or as a background for data.
I do not think you can georeference an Aerial photograph with QGis georeferencer. That plug-in works for images with a constant scale. In an Aerial photograph you do not have a constant scale, since this one is related to the flying height and the focal length of the camera used. Flying height varies according the terrain´s topography. Nevertheless, you can try using grass i.ortho.photo procedure. In my experience it does work when Grass is installed in a linux environment. You can not use it in a Windows OS and I do not have Mac experience. Check this out

http://www.grassbook.org/sample2nd/grassbook_2nd_2004_chapter10_aerial.pdf